# Facebook credits item information problem

Tags: facebook-credits

i have an application using facebook credits. i create item information like title, description and price dynamically, but it gives error like "Item information: Description not specified" or "invalid price". i look for logs and see that all field data is ok. my code is below. anyone having suggestion?

```
    $memcache                   = GetConnectMemcache();
    $cacheKey                   = 'myKey_' . $_REQUEST['buyer'];
    $data                       = $memcache -> get($cacheKey);


    $item['title']          = $data['title'];
    $item['description']        = $data['description']; 
    $item['price']          = (int)$data['price'];      
    $item['image_url']      = $data['image_url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What value do you currently have data['description'] set to?

Can you try this example below with hardcoded values and if that works?

```
 $item['title'] = 'BFF Locket';
 $item['price'] = 1;
 $item['description'] = 'This is a BFF Locket...';
 $item['image_url'] = 'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png';
 $item['product_url'] = 'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png';
```

Let me know what behavior you see when this is hardcoded, then we can more easily debug the issue.